# How to show a certain convergence of measures?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, convergence-divergence

I am studying some techniques to show a type of convergence of measures. Consider the following definition: let $(\mu_n)$ be a sequence of measures and $\mu$ another measure. All measures are defined on the borelians of $\mathbb R^n$. We say that $\mu_n \longrightarrow \mu$, as $n \to \infty$, if
\begin{equation}\label{1}\tag{1}
\mu_n (A) \longrightarrow \mu(A)\quad (\hbox{for all }A \hbox{ continuity set of } \mu, \,\,  0 \notin \bar{A})
\end{equation}

where $\bar A$ is the clousure of $A$.

I suspect that for some measures I have this type of convergence. Certainly, instead of conferring for every Borelian $A$ satisfying the above properties in \eqref{1} is almost impossible. I believe that there must be some theorem that allows me to conclude the convergence of measurements by evaluating only a subclass of Borelians. I think maybe this class is related to the notion of base or subbase of a topology, but I'm really not sure about this and I don't want to risk doing something that isn't right. To make the question more objective, allow me to give a very specific example. Consider the following measures:

$$\mu_n(dx)= |x|^{-r}\mathbb{1}_{(1/n < |x|< 1)}, \quad \mu(dx)= |x|^{-r}\mathbb{1}_{(0 < |x|< 1)}, \quad r \in (2,3)$$
So my **question** is: which class of Borelians (the simplest possible) would be sufficient to conclude that $\mu_n \longrightarrow \mu$ ? Is it enough to show that \eqref{1} holds for $A=[\epsilon < |x|]$, with any $\epsilon >0$?

Comment: In your case, $\mu_n \uparrow \mu$ holds by the monotone convergence.